# HP 1/8 G2 LTO-6 Autoloader upgrade to LTO7

Tags: backup, hp, autoloader

We are looking at getting an HP 1/8 G2 LTO-7 Autoloader. We already have the LTO-6 version, which would become redundant with the introduction of the new one, so rather than waste it, is it possible to upgrade it?

The actual autoloader part looks as though they are exactly the same, the only difference appears to be the internal tape drives.

I found this [forum post](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Tape-Libraries-and-Drives/HP-Autoloader-1-8-G2-upgrade/td-p/1145585) that suggests it was possible with an LTO-3 upgrade to LTO-4, and it retained the autoloader HP support and tape drive HP support.

Does anyone have experience with this process? Is it just as simple as swapping out the internal drive?

Comment: I can't answer for certain sorry but it's a comparitively minor upgrade in terms of that product, in fact you can buy an LTO-7 version of exactly what you have so presumably it's just a drive-swap (plus tapes and labels obviously) - best thing to do is call HPE directly to ask, nothing's leaping out on their product data regarding say a single part number for the upgrade but I imagine it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd call HP.

But think of it this way: The auto-loader mechanism isn't the bulk of the price of the unit. The drive modules are. You can probably upgrade, but is it necessary? If you feel the desire to reuse old equipment, why not keep it as LTO-6? If that's not enough capacity, then your requirements are different and really dictate that should buy another full unit.

Comment: It's probably not necessary but it'd be cheaper which is one of the main goals for us here, since management are not usually forthcoming when it comes to spending money on IT equipment. It's not enough capacity currently, but upgrading the drive to LTO-7 would solve that without the need to replace the whole thing.